# has_many through doesn't work when using same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model `FamilyService`. In the model I have these associations:

```
belongs_to :family
has_many :balance_histories, :through => :family
has_many :balances, :through => :family
```

Executing this command: `FamilyService.where("families.id > 90000").joins(:balances)` works fine. I get:

```
SELECT families_services.*
FROM families_services
INNER JOIN families ON families.id = families_services.family_id
INNER JOIN balances ON balances.family_id = families.id
WHERE (families.id > 90000)
```

Also, executing this query: `FamilyService.where("families.id > 90000").joins(:balance_histories)` gives me this:

```
SELECT families_services.*
FROM families_services
INNER JOIN families ON families.id = families_services.family_id
INNER JOIN balance_histories ON balance_histories.family_id = families.id
WHERE (families.id > 90000)
```

Great!

But when trying to do: `FamilyService.where("families.id > 90000").joins(:balances, :balance_histories)`. I get:

```
SELECT families_services.*
FROM families_services
INNER JOIN families ON families.id = families_services.family_id
INNER JOIN balances ON balances.family_id = families.id
INNER JOIN families families_families_services_join ON families_families_services_join.id = families_services.family_id
INNER JOIN balance_histories ON balance_histories.family_id = families_families_services_join.id
WHERE (families.id > 90000)
```

Which is wrong (**families families_families_services_join ON families_families_services_join.id**).
How to fix?

Comment: is it actually wrong? can you include the description from all 3 models, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated query is actually correct. The line

```
INNER JOIN families families_families_services_join ON ...
```

is just temporarily assigning the name `families_families_services_join` to the table `families` so the query is clearer.

You can, however, simplify the query by specifying your `joins` query as,

```rb
FamilyService.where("families.id > 90000").joins(family: [:balances, :balance_histories])
```

This will generate something like

```
SELECT families_services.*
FROM families_services
INNER JOIN families ON families.id = families_services.family_id
INNER JOIN balances ON balances.family_id = families.id
INNER JOIN balance_histories ON balance_histories.family_id = families.id
WHERE (families.id > 90000)
```

Comment: Great answer. Thx. Can you explain the syntax? Why does it give a different result?